# Style <li> if radiobutton is checked - Howto?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to style a `<li>` wether a radiobutton is checked or not.

Here is the plugin code that I am trying to alter:

```
<div class="gift-certificate-show-form">
    <p><?php _e( 'Vem vill du skicka ditt presentkort till?', 'wc_smart_coupons' ); ?></p>
    <ul class="show_hide_list" style="list-style-type: none;">
        <li>
            <input type="radio" id="hide_form" name="is_gift" value="no" checked="checked" />
            <label for="hide_form">
                <?php _e( 'Skicka presentkortet till mig!', 'wc_smart_coupons' ); ?>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" id="show_form" name="is_gift" value="yes" />
            <label for="show_form">
                <?php _e( 'Till någon annan!', 'wc_smart_coupons' ); ?>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How would I go about to make it happen?

I tried: `

```
show_hide_list input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background: beige !important;
```

but that only backgrounds the text. I want the entire `<li>` highlited. Thanks

Comment: You'll need javascript for that since CSS has no 'parent' selector

Comment: The title contradicts the first sentence. What should happen if it isn't checked?

Answer (score 2):

This will be possible in CSS 4, using the `:has` selector, just like in jQuery. However, as of now, no browser implements it, so you'll have to use JavaScript for that (jQuery will do the job)

Here's some code, just add a `highlighted` CSS class with your style:

```
$(".gift-certificate-show-form :radio").on("click", function() {
    $(this).closest(".gift-certificate-show-form").find("li").removeClass("highlighted");
    $(this).closest("li").addClass("highlighted");
});
```

---

Another way to do the job, as I just noticed the form actually starts with a checked radio:

```
$(function() {
    var updateHighlight = function() {
        $(".gift-certificate-show-form")
            .find("li")
                .removeClass("highlighted")
            .end()
            .find("li:has(:radio:checked)")
                .addClass("highlighted");
    };

    updateHighlight();
    $(".gift-certificate-show-form :radio").on("click", function() {
        updateHighlight();
    });
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/LucasTrz/Yc6Qj/1/

Don't forget to add a reference to jQuery.

Comment: Thank you, I am new to this so please forgive my unexperience, but where do I put this code?

Comment: @RomeoPatrick, put it inside `<script></script>`.  Also, don't forget to wrap the code (inside `script`, of course) with `$(document).ready(function(){ //the code });` so the handler is registered correctly.

Comment: I made a fiddle for you, it shows another way to do the job: http://jsfiddle.net/LucasTrz/Yc6Qj/1/

Comment: Thank you so very much! So the JS you made, I just make a `<script>codehere</script>` and I put that in the same file or in the header? :)

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, you can put it in the header or in the body, it doesn't make a big difference. But put this in the header **above** the code I made: `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>` (or host jQuery on your own server)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a CSS-only solution then try making the radio button a block level element (by setting `display: block;`) and set it's width equal to the container (by setting `width: 100%;`) and style it whatever way you wish based on whether it's checked or not (by specifying a style rule for the `input[type="radio"]:checked` selector).

Comment: Thanks, i have to have it inline, because if i have it "block" then the radiobutton gets messed up :(

Comment: Then your best bet is to use JavaScript.